# AWS AppSync Subscriptions without mutations

Tags: aws-appsync

Reading the AppSync documentation, it seems that AppSync Subscriptions only work by attaching a subscription to a mutation.

But what if I need a subscription that is independent of a mutation? That is fired on some internal state change? For example if a new resource is available?

Is that possible in AppSync?

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible without mutations. I had the same problem months ago and my solution was to create a mutation with [None Data Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-none.html) just to trigger the subscription. This way every time an event was triggered, my Lambda calls the none mutation.

Comment: AppSync team member here, this is the correct answer.